# Java Compare two Arrays of Images / Buttons on GridLayout Panel

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing, shuffle

I have a gridlayout on a JPanel and add JButtons each with an icon and together they form a picture when in proper order.

I then shuffle the array of images (its actually single image cropped using java code into pieces and stored in the array) and then set each JButton icon to a new image.  Now this gives us a nice "puzzle" type of picture where the end-user can swap tiles to put it back in order.

My only problem, is I have no idea how to check to see if they have 1) put an image in its correct location (button) and b) if all images are in the proper location (buttons), to form the original picture.

I do store the buttons in an array, and each image in a separate array.  Only the images get sorted, and only the image icon get set when user swaps two different tiles.

My thought is that I need to compare button[0].image == image[0], etc.  However, I dont know how to do that.

Perhaps my approach is wrong and there are other properties or venues to persue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were implementing this, I would keep an unshuffled array (or list) of images along with an array (or list) of indices into that array. Initialize the second array/list with `index[i] = i`. Then shuffle the array/list of indices. Setting the JButton icons takes an extra level of indirection: `button[i].setIcon(image[index[i]])`. But it makes checking that an image is in the correct location much easier: `if (index[i] == i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `Java Swing` example of a simple puzzle game the same as you are developing. Here I've used numbers but you are using Images instead.

[Java Swing Shuffle Game](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-shuffle-game)

You can use button name as index.

```
JButton btn[index] = new JButton(index,imageIcon) ;
```

So for each move you need to check button indexes are ordered. If ordered, your shuffle is arranged. I hope you can go forward. Have fun.

Comment: I had thought of that, I was under the impression the first arg for that constructor is text that would be displayed to the user.  Also, if the buttons are not moving, but the imageIcons are, Im not sure that would still work since the index would associate with the button not the image?

Comment: @Kairan it should not be displayed right ? You can find a way to hide it. Check button.setText too.